# analysis django input form

Tags: django, python-3.x

i m a new to django i first created a project so i can translat the form input and display it in my app (the translation algorithm is all set )

the form view template are all set

i imported multiple py files that contains the translation code to views.py

in "views.py" i have this :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .forms import PhraseForm

import re
import string
import sys
import argparse
from . import normalize
from .stemming import ArabicStemmer
from . import stem_const            
def get_phrase(request):
    form = PhraseForm(request.POST)
    als = ArabicStemmer();
    text = u""
    var = u""
    ana = u""   
    # check whether it's valid:
    if form.is_valid():
    # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
        texte = form.cleaned_data['ma_phrase']      
        words = normalize.normalize_searchtext(text)
        words = words.split()
        for word in words:  
            als.light_stem(word)
            ana = als.traduction(word)
            var = ana +' '          
        envoi = True                
    return render(request , 'webapp/head.html', locals())
```

envoi is passed to the front end the issue is with 'var'
any clue please help